# Two for loops in one line c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, vector, iteration

My question is regarding two for loops in one line of code. For example:

```
vector < vector<int> > myArray;

for (int i; i > n; i++) for (int j; j > m; j++)
{
//Statements
myArray[i][j];
}
```

Obviously it really is used for 2-dimensional arrays or vectors, but what real practical examples would they be used for? Since it would be hard to display the rows and columns in separate lines. Also, both for loop conditions would change at the same time since they are on the same line, which would be more difficult to control the whole process.

Shortly, what is the practical purpose of this?

Comment: I've never seen it like that in the wild, but it is really just a text formatting thing. Move the 2nd if onto the next line and indent it. Now it's a bit clearer. If I did see it on one line in a review I'd send it back to be re-written to make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the practical purpose of making code harder to read is generally none (which two `for` loops on one line definitely is).  It makes no functional difference to the output of the compiler, whether you use:

```c
for (int i; i > n; i++) for (int j; j > m; j++)
{
    //Statements
    myArray[i][j];
}
```

or

```c
for (int i; i > n; i++) 
{
    for (int j; j > m; j++)
    {
        //Statements
        myArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

However, other than for obfuscation contests, writing code in a way that is hard to read, is bad for maintainability, readability and debugability.  The second option above, is easier to quickly read and understand, and MUCH easier to debug.

There are many style guides that cover this, gives examples of 'good' code, and reasoning for writing code in a certain way.

Have a look at this question for some links: [programming style guide for C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495255/programming-style-guide-for-c)

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. I am up more for the second example you gave. Makes things more readable.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a purpose to using multiple for loops on one line.

```
for (int i; i > n; i++) for (int j; j > m; j++) Statements
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for (int i; i > n; i++) {
    for (int j; j > m; j++) {
        Statements
    }
}
```

Removing braces only changes what the code looks like. In the end it doesn't matter. In some cases it could make your code look cleaner.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It actually makes sense now.